# Is there a functional difference between Const and Static Readonly field value?

Tags: c#

While playing with some code, I noticed that I had a field value as a `static readonly`, so on a whim I changed it to a `const` and it got me wondering -

Is there any real difference between a `const` field value and a `static readonly` field value?